# Symfony captcha not showing

Tags: symfony, captcha

[check error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAiS2.png) I added captcha in my symfony project. it working fine in development mode but not showing captcha image in production mode.

below is link

The image “https://www.sinclus.com/marketing/web/index.php/captcha?reload=1&1560776371” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

i try to clean my cache folder. but still getting error.

Comment: you have to put more information... what code are you using? what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is corrupted because it's outputting part of your template:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?..
```